# After casting my votes to candidates of my choice should I downvote other candidates?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, moderator-election

Question is what title says. I am not sure what to do actually.

Comment: I was asking the exact same question in the chat, and got the same answer as Oded posted. I ended up casting a vote (up and down) on everyone to give my selected nominees  better chance to get into the final phase. Good luck to all the candidates!

Comment: My problem is that they are all  good candidates this time, there isn't anyone I can point to as a "bad" candidate, only good and "gooder" ;) .  Upvoting all 12 is kind of pointless though.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Upvote the candidates you support.

Downvote the candidates you absolutely don't want to see as moderators.

Don't vote on any other candidates.

Comment: Hmm.. unlike many elections, you can downvote candidates.  How strange.  Now I have to hunt down the PHP developers...

Comment: @MartinJames Hunt down the PHP developers? Hmm... *runs away*

Comment: But if they are busy as mods on SO, they have less time to create PHP...

Comment: @SList: Is that an advantage or disadvantage?

Comment: @SList Oh yes!  I missed the 'world would be a better place overall' argument..

Comment: @SList *They* may have less time to create PHP, but they could make it easier for thousands of *other* people to create PHP ...

Comment: @MartinJames _stares in PHP_